# Checkbox not appearing in Winform GridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I am binding a datagridview to a list of objects. One of its columns is a checkbox which is supposed to represent a bool property, the rest are comboboxes and textboxes. Everything is fine, but the checkbox cell is appearing as blank !

Also, when I assign the columntype, each type appears twice in the list e.g. DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn 
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn? why is that happening ?

Comment: What is the code you are using to populate the checkbox column?

Comment: //in the designer

 this.IsFixedReference.DataPropertyName = "IsFixedReference"; this.IsFixedReference.HeaderText = "Fixed"; this.IsFixedReference.Name = "IsFixedReference";

 // in a function 

appDataSeriesBindingSource.DataSource = new List<AppDataSeries>(av.DataSeriesList); // AppDataSeries has IsFixedReference as a boolean property

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had to increase the row height from 17 to 18 !! Figured it out by chance

Comment: Just had this same issue as my row height was 16

Comment: And remember to take any non-zero Top and Bottom padding for your cells into account for this too so that your assigned row-height value is (18 + padding-top + padding-bottom).  If you don't... no checkbox.

Comment: I think I'd never figured it out. It makes sense though.

Answer (score 1):

change AutoSizeRowsMode=AllCells

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).